# Referring to an Access Database table from a TSQL Query

Tags: t-sql, ms-access

I am rebuilding a system so instead of using multiple Access and Excel files the business I am working for, uses SSRS for reporting requirements. Most things are coming along great but I have one sticking point.

One of the Access databases has a table within itself rather than replying on the server data, which is there to keep the grade level of staff up to date (as it is a very complex method on how staff go up a grade).

Now I could easily build a new table in the SQL Server, but I do not want management relying on me for updating this particular table. I could also rebuild the Access database to upload the data to the server which is probably what I will do, but what I wanted to ask first is there a way to join to the table in the Access Database from the T-SQL query, as if it was another table in the main database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Attach the database file under *Server Objects* as a *Linked Server*.

To ease referencing the table in this, create a view in your database that "hides" the needed weird *triple-dot* syntax, like:

```sql
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELDN
FROM THELINKEDSERVERNAME...YourTable AS LinkedYourTable
```

Then use this view to read the table.